# Android:-View pushes upwords while using SoftInputKeyboard

Tags: android, view, android-listview, android-softkeyboard

I know that this question is asked so many times but i tried a lot of things like changing in the **Manifest** with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for an activity but cannot get an output.

Below will provide you my XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/login_screen_textview" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_your_fav_video"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_icon"
                android:hint="Search"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true" >
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/search_listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a1528c8253ca0be"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my mainfest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.favyoutubevideotodownload"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.videotodownload.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchYourVideoActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

</manifest>
```

I think this is due to **Lisview** or **AdView** used in my XML.Can any one suggest me how to do this.

Any helps is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your activity's oncreate

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

instaed of

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

> "adjustPan" --    The activity's main window is not resized to make room
>   for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are
>   automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by
>   the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is
>   generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to
>   close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of
>   the window.

So in adjust pan, the view will be pushed upward if required, to maintain the current focus.

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout to this.... and put android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in manifest......

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/login_screen_textview" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_your_fav_video"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_icon"
                android:hint="Search"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true" >
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/search_listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a1528c8253ca0be"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```